# Prove that $\overline{A}$ is the union of $A$ with the set of its accumulation points.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$. Prove that $\overline{A}$ is the union of $A$ with the set of its accumulation points. Give an example to show that this union may not be disjoint.

**Definition 1.** A point $x \in X$ is the accumulation point of $A$ if for all $V \in \tau$ such that $x \in V$ has $(V - \{x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

**Definition 2.** The closing of $A$ is the intersection of all closed ones that contain $A$ and will be denoted by $\overline{A}$.

We need to prove that $\overline{A}$ is the union of $A$ with the set of its accumulation points.

If $x \in A$ then it is clear that $x \in A$, because $A \subset \overline{A}$, and therefore $x$ is in  union of $A$ with the set of its accumulation points. Now take $x$ in union of $A$ with the set of its accumulation points. This implies that $x \in A$ or is set of its accumulation points. If $x \in A$, it follows that $x \in \overline{A}$, because $A \subset \overline{A}$. And if $x$ is set of its accumulation points so for all $V \in \tau$ such that $x \in V$ has $(V - \{x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (How to finish?).

My question is if every accumulation point an adherent point? if so, how to prove it?

Comment: First I would prove that $A\cup A'$ ($A'$ is the set of accumulation points) is closed so $\overline{A}\subset A\cup A'$, and I would prove that if $B$ is closed then $B'\subset B$ , then $A'\subset \overline {A}'\subset \overline{A}$

Comment: If $B$ and $B^c\cap B'\neq \varnothing$ then $\exists x\in B^c\cap B'$, for any open set $V\ni x$ implies $V\cap B\neq\varnothing$ so $B^c$ is not open, hence $B$ is not closed.

Comment: okay, thank you!!!

Comment: $A\cup A'$ is closed since if $x\in(A\cup A')=A^c\cap A'^c$, then there exists an open set such that $x\in V$ and $V\cap A=\varnothing$ ($x\not\in A$), suppose that for every open set $V\ni x$, $V\cap A'\neq\varnothing$, then for all such $V$ there exists $y\in V\cap A'$, and by definition of $A'$ $V\cap A\neq\varnothing$ so $x\in A'$ wich is absurd.

Comment: For $A = [0,1]$ as an interval in the reals, $A= \overline[A}$ and $A’=A$ too, So the union is far from disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is in $A^{\prime},$ every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ (in a point different trom $x$ ). Therefore, $x$ belongs to $\bar{A}$. Hence $A^{\prime} \subset \bar{A} .$ Since by definition $A \subset \bar{A},$ it follows that $A \cup A^{\prime} \subset \bar{A}$

To demonstrate the reverse inclusion, we let $x$ be a point of $\bar{A}$ and shuw that $x \in A \cup A^{\prime} .$ If $x$ happens to lie in $A,$ it is trivial that $x \in A \cup A^{\prime} ;$ suppose that $x$ does not lie in $A .$ Since $x \in \bar{A},$ we know that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$ because $x \notin A,$ the set $U$ must intersect $A$ in a point different from $x .$ Then $x \in A^{\prime}$ so that $x \in A \cup A^{\prime},$ as desired.